# Is it safe to use FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.getName()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the documentation about [`FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.getId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html#getId%28%29), it is said that the returned unique identifier "is the only representation of the entry that will persist across activity instances".

Is it safe anyway to rely on [`FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.getName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html#getName%28%29) when dealing with back stack changes ? (maybe because the `getId()` description was only valid up to the API level 13)

Or do I misunderstand this part of the documentation ?

Comment: i think it completely depends on how unique your name is going to be, and try to use trim() on your string  when you compare..

Comment: It is going to be completely unique (actually, more than the back stack entry ID itself which can get reused when the back stack is changed), but I was wondering if it could get lost or altered at some point, because the documentation about `FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.getId()` tends to say so. Do you know if this can be the case ?